# How to do live streaming in google glass through android code?

Tags: android, google-glass

How to do live streaming in google glass through android code, i am using eclipse IDE to develop android apps. I have downloaded GDK and created the project using GDK. I have browsed for live video streaming, i didnt get any blogs related to that(i dont know how to use Mirror API to do live streaming )..Can anyone helped me to go up?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the GDK, then you can just use the standard android VideoView or MediaPlayer. It's explained pretty well in the Android API Guide. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

You probably want to build and test this in Android first (a phone or emulator). That should be faster since it's easier to interact with the touch screen. Once you have that working you can load it onto your Glass and proceed from there.

As far as I know there isn't a way to do this with the Mirror API. Only with the GDK.